# File system: ext4 and NFS at the same time?

Tags: filesystems, ext4

At the install of my favourite Linux distro I chose ext4 as my file system. Can my system now make parts of its space (e.g. `/home/myname/myfolder`) available via NFS? In other words: can `/home/myname/myfolder` have more than 1 "file system status" (ext4 AND NFS)? Because I already chose ext4 at the install ... ?

Comment: NFS is not a filesystem in that sense. It's a protocol over which a filesystem interface is made available. You can not format a partition as "NFS".

Comment: but NFS means "network file system"? that's unfortunate naming I guess :) so I can make an ext4 folder available via NFS, but the file system still remains ext4. got it.

Comment: but when I use the "mount" command I get the following information about a NFS network share: "type nfs". Whereas some others have "type ext3". this doesn't seem to fit your answer?

Comment: When, on a client, you mount an NFS filesystem, you instruct the local NFS daemon to connect to the corresponding daemon on the server machine.  The server NFS daemon talks to the native filesystem (be it ext4 or anything else). At no point is there a "physical NFS-formatted filesystem".

Comment: okay thanks! and if I'm im on the client with the mounted share, do I have a chance to see which file system is behind the servers NFS daemon?

Comment: No, not without logging in on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but what you're suggesting is strange...

Generally you use a network filesystem (such as NFS) to make a filesystem available to **another** (remote) machine rather than looping it back to the same machine (if you want to do that a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198591/109111) will be more efficient). So if you are only mounting the NFS share on another machine why would the original system see the same "region" via two different filesystems?

(also technically this isn't a programming question)